# R - Keras - Error message

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I was testing out the Keras as per https://keras.rstudio.com/

When I tried to run the code

```
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Your current architecture is 32bit however this version of
>   Python is compiled for 64bit.

Can someone please help with this? I really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: are you using 64bit R?

Comment: Yes I am using 64bit R.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I did 2 things:
1. Install keras with the following command line

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

2. Installed Rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html

Don't know which one did the trick but now `keras` works smoothly in my 64-bit laptop.